# Using django crispy form, how do you set extra_context in the Field method of the Layout object?

Tags: django-crispy-forms

I am using crispy forms 1.6 with django 1.9 and python 3.4.

In using the Field class with a Layout , I am not able to get the extra_context to work. The values are not being injected into the context.

The template below fails to output the "threshold" value.

Here is my form code.

```
# project_edit_form.py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from .models import Projects
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, HTML

class ProjectEditForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Projects
        fields = ('project_description', 'location', 'days_elapsed',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        # ...
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Fieldset(
            'Project',
            'project_description', 
            'location', 
            Field('days_pge_first_responded', template="days_elapsed_field.html", extra_context={"threshold":15})%}"),
        ),
    )
    super(ProjectEditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And here is the html template for the Field:

```
# days_elapsed_field.html
extra_context.threshold: {{ extra_context.threshold }}
threshold: {{ threshold }}
field.threshold: {{ field.threshold }}

<div id="div_id_{{ field_name }}" class="form-group"> 
    <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="control-label"> {{ field.label }} </label> 
    <div > 
        <input 
            style="{% if field.value > threshold %} background-color:#FFE8E8; {% else %}  background-color:#e3e3e3 {% endif %}" 
            class="textinput textInput form-control" id="{{ field.id}}" name="{{ field.name}}" readonly="True" type="text" value="{{ field.value }}" />
    </div> 
</div>
```

And here is the main html template:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal" >
            {% crispy form %}
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out a built-in way of doing it, so I just created a generic class and used that instead.  You can pass `extra_context` as a `kwarg` to `CustomCrispyField`.  `extra_context` is just a dictionary that I access in my custom template that I copied from `crispy_forms`.

```
from crispy_forms.layout import Field
from crispy_forms.utils import TEMPLATE_PACK


class CustomCrispyField(Field):
    extra_context = {}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.extra_context = kwargs.pop('extra_context', self.extra_context)
        super(CustomCrispyField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def render(self, form, form_style, context, template_pack=TEMPLATE_PACK, extra_context=None, **kwargs):
        if self.extra_context:
            extra_context = extra_context.update(self.extra_context) if extra_context else self.extra_context
        return super(CustomCrispyField, self).render(form, form_style, context, template_pack, extra_context, **kwargs)
```

And I would use it like so in my form:

```
self.helper.layout=Div(CustomCrispyField('my_model_field', css_class="col-xs-3", template='general/custom.html', extra_context={'css_class_extra': 'value1', 'caption': 'value2'})
```

And my template would have code similar to the following:

```
{% crispy_field field %}
<button class="btn {{ css_class_extra }}">{{ caption }}</button>
```